# eccrypto.getPublic() does not work on "custom" private keys

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ethereum, ecdsa

I'm trying to generate an Ethereum key couple in JavaScript.

In order to do that, I'm testing a few ECDSA/Keccak256 algorithms to get a public key from a private key. The most promising one I found (knowing the constraint that I want to avoid pseudo-random only for the private key) is this one: https://github.com/bitchan/eccrypto

I've been able to generate a private key and get a public key using the two functions of the lib:

```js
const privateKey2 = eccrypto.generatePrivate();
        console.log(privateKey2);
        const publicKey = eccrypto.getPublic(privateKey2);
        console.log(publicKey);
```

However, whenever I try to use getPublic on a privateKey that was not generated by eccrypto **immediately** before, the eccrypto.getPublic won't work and will reject with the error `Bad private key`.

The weirdest thing is that even when I copy a generated private key by eccrypto and try to pass it to `eccrypto.getPublic()` (hard-coded), I get the same error:

```js
const TypedTable = new Uint8Array([
            235,
            78,
            133,
            244,
            5,
            163,
            18,
            32,
            218,
            162,
            173,
            132,
            214,
            16,
            57,
            100,
            122,
            48,
            167,
            30,
            203,
            69,
            52,
            48,
            30,
            99,
            20,
            32,
            249,
            210,
            140,
            48
        ]);

const publicKey = eccrypto.getPublic(TypedTable);
```

It is a very specific problem, but if anyone has a solution, it would really help me!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to convert your private key to a `Buffer` before passing it, there is an `isScalar` method in there that uses `isBuffer` and it expects an actual `Buffer` object.

You should be able to create it from your array using [`Buffer.from(array)`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array).

Comment: Hi, I actually went to another library and indeed, the format expected was Buffer and it worked just fine. The lib I went using is secp256k1, just in case people would have the same problem.
Thanks for your answer!